# Error when start new SharePoint project in visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am a new administrator to a SharePoint farm and I want to start developing **web-parts** for our sites.

In our company we have installed **SharePoint 2010** on **Windows Server 2008 R2.**

And we have installed **Microsoft visual studio 2010** on that server.

We also have **Microsoft SQL server management studio** installed in the same server.
In my computer (**Windows 7 professional**), I have used **remote desktop connection** to access that server.

From **SharePoint central administration**, I have created new application, new site collection and new site.

I started VS with admin rights.

From File => New => Project =>Visual basic => SharePoint =>2010 => Empty SharePoint project => ok

Then I got a dialog box asking me to enter the local site that I want to use for debugging. 
I entered: "http://sharepoint:21029/team1/"

I chose **deploy as a farm solution** checkbox.

Click Validate.

The problem is:

When I click **Validate**, I get the following error:

**Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: "http://sharepoint:21029/team1/"  Make sure that the Site URL is valid, that the SharePoint site is running on the local computer, and that the current user as the necessary permissions to access the site.**

---

I made a lot of searches on the internet and finally I found this link:

http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/19/resolving-vs-2010-solution-deployment-issues-for-sharepoint-2010-projects/

When I tried to solve my problem as described in the previous link, I could not find the following databases:

**SharePoint_Config**

**SharePoint_AdminContent_[guid]**

**SharePoint Site Content DB**

Why I could not find the databases in the SQL Management Studio?
And why I get the error?

I want to start developing web-parts in visual studio... Any help please!!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution finally :)

I found this critical in Event Viewer:

SQL database log in for 'SharePoint_Config' on instance 'sharepoint' failed.

I did the following steps and it solves my issue and I can now connect visual studio to my SharePoint site successfully ^_^

---

**Grant correct permissions to the database access account**

**To resolve this issue, assign the database access account and then verify that the account has correct permission in SQL Server.**

**To assign the database access account:**

1. On the Central Administration Web page, on the Quick Launch, click Security, and in the General Security section click Configure service accounts.
2. In the Credential Management section, in the upper drop-down list click the correct Web application pool for your Web application.
3. In the Select an account for this component drop-down list, click the domain account with which you want to associate this Web application pool, or click Register new managed account to associate a new domain account with this application pool.
4. Click OK to save changes.

---

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

What is team1?  a sub site?

Try using the root site collection:

```
  http://sharepoint:21029/
```

If you install sp in standalone mode read [here](http://sharepointthing.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/how-to-connect-to-the-sharepoint-services-integrated-database-with-sql-server-management-studio-express/) about the connection string because sp uses an embedded edition of SQL server